# how to parse this this response structure using model class in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

[image]

I am new in parsing and using alamofire for api calling.Here i tried fot model class. Below i my class and reponse json structure.

```
class EventsDate: NSObject {

var eventDate = Date()
var eventIcon = String()

}
```

Comment: I got this solution for my problem https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome tool supporting parsing JSON to Swift model. Its name is SwiftyJSONAccelerator, you can read more about this tool at this [SwiftyJSONAccelerator](https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy in swift to parse the JSON response using model class. You can read this wonderful [Json Parsing in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) blog from Apple.